# Is there any scientific literature on the "shower principle" (i.e., taking a break from a task leads to unexpected insights)?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, reference-request

Folk cognitive psychology has it that doing activities that remove you from your intellectual work (such as taking a shower or, like Einstein is reported to have done when it a rut, playing the violin) increases your chances of having unexpected insights. Is there a name for this phenomenon and a dedicated scientific literature for it?

Comment: See also [How is it that taking a break from a problem sometimes allows you to figure out the answer?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-is-it-that-taking-a-break-from-a-problem-sometimes-allows-you-to-figure-out)

Answer (score 4):

That moment is often called the "aha moment", the [Eureka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_effect) effect, or more generally, insight.  There is literature on it, but as you might expect, it is a pretty difficult thing to produce in a lab.

Some references:
The AHA! experience: Creativity through emergent binding in neural networks.
Thagard, Paul; Stewart, Terrence C.. Cognitive Science35.1 (Jan-Feb 2011): 1-33.

Gaining insight into the "aha" experience.
Topolinski, Sascha Reber, Rolf. Current Directions in Psychological Science19.6(Dec 2010): 402-405.

The aha! Moment: The cognitive neuroscience of insight.
Kounios, John; Beeman, Mark. Current Directions in Psychological Science18.4(Aug 2009): 210-216.

Neural correlates of the “aha” experiences: Evidence from an fMRI study of insight problem solving.
Qiu, JiangView Profile; Li, Hong; Jou, JerwenView Profile; Liu, Jia; Luo, Yuejia; et al. Cortex: A Journal Devoted to the Study of the Nervous System and Behavior46.3 (Mar 2010): 397-403.