# Effects of quantity and quality of breaks on learning

Tags: learning, motivation, attention, brain-training

Are there papers which discuss the effects of quantity and quality of breaks during learning? Do state of the art papers have a common ground?

So far I have found these papers:

- [The Fourth R: Recess and Its Link to Learning](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00131720108984795)
- [The effects of different recess timing regimens on preschoolers' classroom attention](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/03004430500207179)

Unfortunately, both focus on kids and learning in school. The second article even on preschoolers. So I'm not sure, if the hypotheses also apply to adults. Also they're from 2007 and 2008, resp.

Comment: there are a lot of ways that an answer might be framed. what is your endpoint of interest? for example, i would consider the phenomenon of cramming versus spaced-learning on performance to map perfectly to what you're asking.

Comment: I'm considering to change the frequency and structure of my pauses during learning, but I'm pleased with gaining any knowledge on this topic. So don't want to narrow down the frame of the answer, if the question - as is - is not too broad.

Comment: Cramming and spaced-learning can be expressed via quantity and quality of breaks, at least to some extent. This question leaves out the quality/quantity of the learning (methods) itself and thus could be shortsighted, if that's what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: 1. what do you expect they will do during breaks -- eat well, perhaps revise? 2. what is it that follows after the break? e.g. some entirely new topic, or expanding concepts contingent upon prior learning. 3. are they adults?

Comment: What they'll do during the breaks is quality of the break. It was part of my question. As for the other information, I can't specify it - except that I'm interested in adults. Maybe I can make that aspect clearer in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56195/discussion-between-faustus-and-mike).

Comment: Hi mike. We have a somewhat related question over here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/1/11318 which might give you a nice start on some reading. I'm not able to give you an answer about the quality or quantity of breaks but I hope someone will :)